# Function for checking data type for several data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, class, radix, typeof

I would like to create a function, where the argument (**input**) would be unknown amount of data frames (could vary) and **output** is the data frame with data type for each column of data frames from the input.

Example: I have 2 data frames below (amount of data frames can vary, so I am not sure how to pass it as a function argument).

```
# Dataframe 1
kpi_id <- c("SL",  "OOS")
kpi_val <- c (1,2)

df1 <-  data.frame(kpi_id,   kpi_val)

> sapply(df1, class)

   kpi_id     kpi_val 
"character"   "numeric"

# Dataframe 2
kpi_id <- c("SL",  "OOS")
kpi_val <- c ("3", "4")

df2 <-  data.frame(kpi_id,   kpi_val)

> sapply(df2, class)
  kpi_id     kpi_val 
"character" "character"
```

I can get a result in a simple manner as below:

```
df_types1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df1, class)) 
colnames(df_types)[1] <- deparse(substitute(df1))


df_types2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df2, class)) 
colnames(df_types)[1] <- deparse(substitute(df2))


df_types3 <- bind_cols(df_types1, df_types2)

> df_types3
              df1       df2
kpi_id  character   character
kpi_val   numeric   character
```

How can I create a function where initial amount of data frames is unknown to get the same output?

Comment: put your dataframes in a list, and loop over them using `*apply` function eg `sapply(my_list, function(x)sapply(x, class))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rapply`.

```
rapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), class, how='l') |>
  do.call(what='cbind')
#                 df1         df2        
# kpi_id  "character" "character"
# kpi_val "numeric"   "character"
```

If you get weird output due to multiple classes,

```
df1$date <- df2$date <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())

rapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), class, how='l') |>
  do.call(what='cbind')
#                df1         df2        
# kpi_id  "character" "character"
# kpi_val "numeric"   "character"
# date    character,2 character,2
```

you could use `data.class` which returns just the first one:

```
rapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), data.class, how='l') |>
  do.call(what='cbind')
#                df1         df2        
# kpi_id  "character" "character"
# kpi_val "numeric"   "character"
# date    "POSIXct"   "POSIXct"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use; pass a list of data frames, whether that list is named, or unnamed:

```
df_types <- function(dfs) {
  do.call(
    rbind, 
    lapply(seq_along(dfs), function(d) {
        data.frame(
          df = ifelse(is.null(names(dfs)), rep(d,ncol(dfs[[d]])), names(dfs)[d]),
          col = names(dfs[[d]]),
          type=sapply(dfs[[d]],typeof),row.names = NULL)
      })
  )
}
```

Usage

```
df_types(list("a" = df1,"b" = df2))
```

Output:

```
  df     col      type
1  a  kpi_id character
2  a kpi_val    double
3  b  kpi_id character
4  b kpi_val character
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `tidyverse` with the addition of using `janitor` and `data.table` to get it into the desired format:

```
library(tidyverse)

lst(df1, df2) %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ map_df(.x, class), .id = "var") %>%
  data.table::transpose(keep.names = "var") %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(1) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  column_to_rownames("var")
```

**Output**

```
              df1       df2
kpi_id  character character
kpi_val   numeric character
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(janitor)
compare_df_cols(df1, df2)
```

```
  column_name       df1       df2
1      kpi_id character character
2     kpi_val   numeric character
```